# How can i use data object in stimul soft report?

Tags: c#, wpf, report, code-first, stimulsoft

I have two class in wpf project and can you see the following :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String LName { get; set; }
    public Company Companys { get; set; }
}
 public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

and the following  code for Fill the data object and use it in stimulsoft

```
Employee emp = new Employee()
            {
                Companys = new Company() {Id = 1, Name = "Ava"},
                LName = "Tavazoei",
                Name = "Javad"
            };
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load(
            new Uri(
                "pack://application:,,,/Users/SayeGostaran/Documents/visual studio2012/Projects/TestWpfProject/TestWpfProject/ReportTest1.mrt")
                .LocalPath);
        report.RegBusinessObject("Emp", "Emp", emp);
        report.ShowWithWpf();
```

now i want to use Company name in company class but the stimulsoft cant to find it.

Comment: can you share your report(mrt) file?

Answer (score 0):

You shold synchronize Business objects with next code:

```
report.RegBusinessObject("Emp", "Emp", emp);
report.Dictionary.SynchronizeBusinessObjects(3);
report.ShowWithWpf();
```